# How would one access each element in a mulidimensional array without using #flatten?

Tags: arrays

I already flunked an assessment a little while ago but this question is still bugging me. The idea is to add all the elements of a multidimensional array like this: `[1,[2,3],4,[5,6,[7]]]]` and add them up as if they were all one-line, like `1+2+3+4+5+6+7`, without being able to use `#flatten`. I got about as far as removing all the integers (like 1 and 4) and adding them into its own variable and then trying to reduce(:+) the 2nd level arrays( `[2,3]`, etc), but I can't figure out how to write a loop that will delve deeper into the dimensions, like the `[7]`. How would one do that?

Code I've tried thus far

```
def multi_array_sum(arrays)
    #need to add up all array elements
    num = 0
    arr = {}
    arrays.each {|int| num = num + int if int.class == Fixnum; arrays.delete(int)}
    array.map do |numz|
        num = num + numz.reduce(:+)
    end    
end
```

Comment: What is the target language?  Ruby?  What have you already tried (paste your example code here)?

Comment: yes Ruby. Gimme one sec n the code.